# Office Professional Plus 2016 Upgrade not taking affect

Tags: microsoft-office

I am trying to upgrade to Office Professional Plus 2016 from 2013.

The upgrade appears to have gone well, however I'm not seeing any Office 2016 apps e.g Outlook, Word etc.

Can someone let me know if I really need to uninstall 2013 before installing 2016?

The one thing I noticed when I checked the Programs list is that there isn't a size for 2016, see image.

[image: office2016]

Thanks

Comment: Which edition of Office 2013 did you purchased?

Comment: I purchased Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013

Comment: Try to use easy fix tool to uninstall Office complete: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/uninstall-office-from-a-pc-9dd49b83-264a-477a-8fcc-2fdf5dbf61d8  Then re-install Office 2016.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to simply remove Office 2013 after installing Office 2016. After that, all applications were running Office 2016